# Why does this SELECT query work, but fails when I try to SELECT INTO?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following select query, which runs fine as expected (its purpose is to build a list of words from strings in another table):

```
SELECT UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(allWords.words)))
FROM
(
    SELECT section.Cols.value('.', 'varchar(250)') words
    FROM @xml.nodes('/c') section(Cols)
) AS allWords
WHERE 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(words)) <> ''
    AND dbo.RegExIsMatch('.*[\W\d].*',LTRIM(RTRIM(words)),1) <> 1
    AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(words))) > 3
GROUP BY words
```

But when I add the `INTO` declaration it fails:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('usr.nameList') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE usr.nameList;

SELECT UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(allWords.words)))
INTO usr.nameList
FROM
(
    SELECT section.Cols.value('.', 'varchar(250)') words
    FROM @xml.nodes('/c') section(Cols)
) AS allWords
WHERE 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(words)) <> ''
    AND dbo.RegExIsMatch('.*[\W\d].*',LTRIM(RTRIM(words)),1) <> 1
    AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(words))) > 3
GROUP BY words
```

Output is:

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO
>   statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look
>   for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed.
>   Change the alias to a valid name.

If the `SELECT` query works, why would such a simple modification to insert the data into a new table fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you missing in the error message?  You need to give the column a name:

```
SELECT UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(allWords.words))) as words
INTO usr.nameList
FROM
(
    SELECT section.Cols.value('.', 'varchar(250)') words
    FROM @xml.nodes('/c') section(Cols)
) AS allWords
WHERE 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(words)) <> ''
    AND dbo.RegExIsMatch('.*[\W\d].*',LTRIM(RTRIM(words)),1) <> 1
    AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(words))) > 3
GROUP BY words;
```